# C++ implicitly calling class member's constructor when initializing the class instance

Tags: c++, constructor

I'm still learning the beauty of C++. I came across some code today and hopefully someone can give me some guidance.
I have 2 classes

```
class B
{
public:
    B( std::string s )
        : m_string( s )
    {
    }

private:
    std::string m_string;
};

class A
{
public:
    A( B b )
        : m_b( b )
    {
    }

private:
    B m_b;
};
```

Main.cpp

```
A a = A(std::string("hello"));
```

I'm a bit confused about how can such initialization work? How does the compiler know that the `std::string("hello)` is to be passed to B's constructor instead?

I was trying to find relevant documentation but no luck..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a class has a constructor taking a single argument, that constructor can be used to implicitly convert that argument to an instance of that class.  This means that wherever a `B` is required, your `B( std::string s )` constructor allows passing a string instead.

If you want to inhibit this implicit conversion, you write `explicit B( std::string s )`.  Some people consider this good practice for most single-argument constructors.